# How tomcat-jdbc DataSource will behave in db Switchover?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, tomcat, datasource

Here is one of cloud environment , where we have  DB setup

```
DB-A is master
DB-B is slave
```

and below is the Tomcat-JDBC Datasource Configuration

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverMapping.get(dbType));
        ds.setUrl(dbUrl);
        ds.setUsername(dbUsername);
        ds.setPassword(decryptPassword(dbPassword));
        ds.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        ds.setMaxActive(maxActive);
        ds.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        ds.setMinIdle(minIdle);
        ds.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);
        ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(minEvictableIdleTimeMillis);
        ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(timeBetweenEvicRunsMillis);
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(validationQuery)) {
            ds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        } else if (dbType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Database.ORACLE)) {
            ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
        } else {
            ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        }
        ds.setValidationInterval(validationInterval);

        ds.setRemoveAbandoned(removeAbandoned);
        ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(removeAbandonedTimeOut);
        ds.setLogValidationErrors(logValidationErrors);

        return ds;
    }
```

So here is the other details about properties

```
initial-size:10;
max-active:20;
max-idle:10;
min-idle:5;
test-while-idle:true;
time-between-eviction-runs-millis:5000;
min-evictable-idle-time-millis:60000;
test-On-Borrow:true;
```

Suppose no db operation is happening so it mean right now `DataSource` , `min-idle:5` holding 5 idle connection with  `DB-A`

Now some point of time Switchover happened and
DB-A become slave
DB-B become master
and now a `update` query request came from the application , So as per me understanding about the Datasource ,it will borrow[Before Borrowing it will validate with query `Select 1;` and it will get true because master become slave and it have read rights ] a connection from the min-idle connection will be allocated to perform `update` operation .
But update will be fail because update operation is performing in slave db(DB-A).

So my questions are

- After borrowing a connection from Connection pool what will happen to min-idle ,as one connection borrowed for update operation so now it will contain only 4 idle connection or a new DB connection will be created and added to min-idle?
- As all connection in min-idle is connected to DB-A so any update query will fail but upto how many try?
- When DataSource will start querying from DB-B because DB-B become master.

Comment: Apache default DB pool implementation is Apache Commons DBCP (a package modified version with minor changes). This link could be useful: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html Another connection will be instantiated to the DB that will not perform UPDATE operation. One way is to implement your connection factory. refer: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JNDI_Factory_and_Type there is a configuration example with factory